# Laravel API response Unauthenticated even when Authentication is passed

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-7, laravel-authentication, laravel-jwt

I am using the jwt for creating the tokens while login. After I login, I try to hit the /me api pointing to the function:

```
     public function me()
        {
            $user = auth()->user();
            return response()->json($user);
        }
```

I followed the JWT official documentation, initially I was able to get the response for the API. Suddenly it started throwing a

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Why is this happening?? Is there any workaround? It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: did u setup your middleware correctly?

Comment: It was working with the same exact setup?, are you using postman?

Comment: I did it exactly the way recommended in the JWT Docs, @Atlas-Pio

Comment: @Menawer. Exactly. It was working fine with the same setup until I installed hashids/hashids package. After I implemented the hashids, it kept giving the Unauthenticated message. Yes, I am using Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried documentation setup and worked fine, you might missed passing authentication header in your api call. since idk what's your setup i can only tell when you logged in, you should use received token in api calls with authentication.

PostMan Software: In headers tab add a key as `Authorization` and assign token for value with `Bearer`, like `Breaer token...`...

for more help please clarify how you're trying api calls.

Edit: added an alternate way for using middleware

Another way of implementing or using middleware :

Create a Middleware with JWT name and put below code in handle function

```
Don't forget to import
use JWAuth;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in Kernel add jwt to $routeMiddleware like this :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // you should add below code.
    'jwt' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWT::class,
];
```

in `routes/api`

```
Route::apiResource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

now in PostController add your middleware to Constructor like this.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('jwt', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
}
```

So in construct you will set your `middleware` base on JWT, then with `except` you  can modify which one of your functions don't need to authentication base on JWT token. now when you use `auth()->user()` you can get your info or etc.

So if i had `index, show, update, delete, store, create` when i try to do API call if i use `GET METHOD` for `url.com/posts` or `url.com/posts/23` i can get my posts without passing `JWT` token.

When you tried to use `JWT` you should realize that it's working base on token you're passing, you're getting token when you using login, but you're not getting user info because you're not passing user's token to app, before all of this you should consider to verify token then do the rest Logics. Good Luck.

Edit : added more info

auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Thanks @Atlas-Pio. This raised another error "The token could not be parsed from the request." Any idea what this is? Tried all the fixes in the other StackOverflow posts. Doest seem to work.

Comment: ```Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt']], function () {
    Route::get('me', 'Api\AuthController@me');
});```
This is the route i m trying to hit from the Postman with ```Accept: application/json``` and the Bearer token in Authorization (received after login) as header.

Comment: earlier I was using the ```auth:api``` middleware and changed it as per your guidance from the above comment @Atlas-Pio

Comment: Man thanks a lot. I rechecked it with your comment. I think my middleware wasn't set right. Couldn't figure it out as I am just learning Laravel. Thanks a lot. You are a savior man!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem, and the selected solution do solve it. Check the following: if you go alway respose{ "message": "Unauthenticated." } The solution is adding this to .htaccess of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```